# Using preg_match to get content between tags

Tags: php

I need some help using preg_match to get from this html code the name that is between “transferencia de” and “por” and also get the amount between “por” and “en su cuenta” thanks in advance.

```
<span style=3D"font-weight:bold;color:#000000"> Bancolombia in=
forma recepci=C3=B3n transferencia de LUISA PEREZ por $999,000 en su 
cuenta *=
2465. 13/12/2018 02:11. Dudas 018000931987.</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = 'Bancolombia in=
forma recepci=C3=B3n transferencia de LUISA PEREZ por $999,000 en su cuenta *= 2465. 13/12/2018 02:11. Dudas 018000931987.';


preg_match('/(?<=transferencia de)(.*)(?=por)/', $data, $name);
echo $name[1];


preg_match('/(?<=por)(.*)(?=en su cuenta)/', $data, $money);
echo $money[1];
```

Just used a simple regex since you know the words that your output is between, it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$fullstring = 'this is my [tag]dog[/tag]';
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '[tag]', '[/tag]');

echo $parsed; // (result = dog)`enter code here`
```